# TYPO3 Contact form plugin exists twice, also submitted twice

Tags: typo3

I have a submit form that is once displayed in a PopUp and once shown normal on the page. So I created it in a storage folder and used "insert record" for said plugin twice.

When I submit one of the shown forms, it will be executed twice. Anyone ever had this kind of problem?

The contact request form is selfmade.

Comment: Is the popup a real browser popup, aka new window, or is it just a JS modal?

Comment: It's a modal, all the code is in the markup, no Ajax on submit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to distinct your two plugins from each other. I assume you have two times the same plugin on the same page. If you submit your form, both of the plugins respond to the request, because they both feel responsible for it.
If you could give one of the plugins a different name, it would just respond to its own form, and the other plugin would not respond to the other plugins form.

Answer (score 1):

try to modify your plugin so you can configure it to only show the form.then you use two different CEs: one to show only the form, the second to show the form and to handle the submit.

Other possibility: while you are handling the form store the information about handling somewhere and avoid a second handling on the same call